# Execute the Code in a PHP Page And Echo the HTML Output

Tags: php, templates, echo, file-get-contents, execute

I absolutely don't post a question here in SO unless I really can't find a way to solve my problem myself. I did a lot of googling and was not able to find a solution for this one problem I am about to describe.

Here is the problem. I am creating a templated php website. With templated I mean something like below:

```html
<?php include("header.php");?>
<div id="content">
 <div id="main">
  <h2><?php echo($page_title);?></h2>
  <?php 
   echo ($page_content);
  ?>
 </div>
 <?php include("sidebar.php");?>
</div>
<?php include("footer.php");?>
```

As you can see here page template ECHOES the content of the $page_content variable between header and footer sections to build the page. 
To keep the code clean and separated (in my own way) I have been placing the html content in .txt files (let's say page1_content.txt) and assigning the txt content to this variable ($page_content) as below:

```html
$page_content = file_get_contents("page1_content.txt");
```

My problem starts when I place some php code in page1_content.txt, lets' call this file page2_content.php (yes, I change the file from .txt to .php). Then I assign the content of this file to $page_content variable as below as usual:

```html
$page_content = file_get_contents("page2_content.php");
```

Now, when the page template ECHOES page2_content.php contents the php code in it is also echoed as string and not executed, but I am trying to query a database and do some stuff in this file with some php code. I mean, I want the php code inside page2_content.php to be executed and the cumulative html code to be echoed by the "echo" line inside the template file.

How can I achieve this?
Please ask me any questions if you need more info/clarification.

Thanks

**EDİT:** 
As many people here suggested the solution was including the file. Actually, I tried including the file before but it didn't look like it was working, it broke my template, so I though I was on the wrong track and quit the "include" way of doing this. Since everybody here is advising to use include I tried that again. I replaced the php code in "page2_content.php" with a basic 1-line code just to see if it gets executed before adding generated html code without breaking the template and it worked. Apparently my php code had a problem at first place and hence broke my template execution.

Now I have changed the template structure slightly and pages using the template, and it seems to work nicely. Thanks a lot everybody. I have up-voted every answer suggesting that I use include :)

Comment: Try include them instead of file_get_contents if they have php scripts

Comment: Look into [include](https://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and possibly [eval()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Comment: Eval won't work for my case I tried that. I also tried including the file and my template got broken somehow. I will try including again. May be my php code is faulty and that is why the template breaks. Thanks.

Comment: @AliTorabi I would mark your post as answer if it was an answer not a comment. Thanks a lot... :)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is to include your content PHP file, not echo it (as you are doing with `header.php` and `footer.php`).

```
echo($page_content);
```

Would become as below:

```
include("page2_content.php");
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Ali suggested, you could include the files. The other option which I highly suggest you **do not** use is the [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function.

Comment: Yes, include worked. Eval doesn't work in my case. I think eval works only for pure php not for files including a mixture of html and php.

Answer (score 1):

You've already done this in your footer and sidebar, just use include()